# how to make an infinite map with html and js

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I'm trying to implement a seemingly dynamic infinite map of divs.
My main issues are how to generate new tiles in any direction when the user drag the board
and then what/how should the map be stored in the database .

[Here](http://jsbin.com/unanuf/31) is the quick start I have.

Comment: I don't see why this deserves a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the grid is just large as opposed to truly infinite.

You only store the tiles that are placed.

The 'view' of the board is limited, even the minimap version is only about 256x256.

The 'empty' board can be just draw, derived from the top left( or other single point ) and width and depth of the screen.

You could also use a pseudo random number to procedurally vary the appearance of each blank square.

Comment: that's alrealy what i do with the empty board, but it runs out if you keep dragging, I would like to make this initial empty board grows in any dragged direction

Comment: if your view is 200 pixels wide, each tile is say 50, then draw 4 empty tiles, you dont need to 'store' empty tiles, you know they are there, you just draw them, offset by current view.

Comment: i will try that, thanks - (yeah the test code is not pretty...)

Comment: if your VIEW is 10 tiles square, create a grid 30x30 and centre it within your view div. You may not need such a large grid, but having this 10 width border of tiles allows the browser to scroll the grid on dragging. Now when the user does drag, you recentre the grid in the middle of the VIEW, offset by the some pixels to make it appear scrolled. At the same tile you keep track of and adjust the offset into your data grid...And then 'draw' any visible tiles in the grid

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to store the coordinates of each word in an R-Tree. You would then use the R-Tree to find all the words within the coordinate boundaries you like to see. This could be done in your backend (many database systems support indexing spatial coordinates).

Comment: If i just want a blank map, not a map of words, would that work ?

Comment: I guess you will place something on the map, it won't be just a uniform color, right? You can use this to track anything that has coordinates and a defined shape.

Comment: ok that would be useful when i start tracking data to be saved, thanks